# IBMi DB2 SQL create table - table description text

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange, ddl, db2-400

I'm creating sql/ddl descriped tables with "Create Table ..." and so on.

How to add a text/desciption to the table/file? When you are doing dds files, it will just adapt the text from the sourcemember..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to issue a `LABEL ON` statement...

```
create table mytable (                     
 mylongkeyname for column mykey char(10)   
, mydatafield  for column mydata char(50)  
, primary key (mylongkeyname));             

label on table mytable is 'My test table description';
```

You can also use `LABEL ON` to assign column headings and column text...

Columns headings are set as three lines of twenty characters and show up in STRSQL for instance.  Column text is just a string.

```
label on column mytable (
  mylongkeyname is 'My long             Key                 Name'
, mydata        is 'My                  Data'
);

label on column mytable (
  mylongkeyname TEXT is 'My long Key Name'
, mydata        TEXT is 'My Data'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`COMMENT` statement](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzxcomnt.htm):

```
COMMENT ON TABLE blah IS 'whatever'
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "doing the trick". It's not a trick, it's an SQL statement.

Comment: That means it doesn't do what the OP requested.